# If $a/s$ is irreducible in $R_{S}$, then $a$ is irreducible in $R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, factoring, unique-factorization-domains

> Let $R$ be a UFD, and let $S$ be a multiplicative subset of $R$ containing the unity of $R$. Show that if $a/s$ is irreducible in $R_{S}$, then $a$ is irreducible in $R$. (Bhattacharya, *Basic Abstract Algebra*, Example 1.7, page 227.)

I showed that if $a$ is irreducible in $R$, then $a/1$ is irreducible. (I don't know that it is useful.)

What I did :

Let $a=xy$. Since $a/s=xy/s=(x/1)(y/s)$ is irreducible, $x/1$ or $y/s$ is irreducible. If $x/1$ is unit, we done. Let $y/s$ be unit. It means that $y/1=s_{1}/s_{2}$, $ys_{2}=s_{1}$. We should show that $y$ is a unit.

Do $ys_{2}=s_{1}$ imply that $y$ is a unit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your claim is wrong: take $R=\mathbb Z$ and $S=\{1,2,\dots, 2^n,\dots\}$, $a=6$ and $s=2$.

Comment: @Guillermo If the book asks to prove that $a/s$ irreducible implies $a/s$ prime, then the book is right. But this is a different question and you should post it separately.

Comment: The book says that $a/s$ irreducible implies $a$ irreducible and use that fact to show that $a/s$ is prime.

Comment: @Guillermo Then the book is *partially* wrong :)

Comment: You should try to erase the third word from your first comment, @Guillermo, and also: what book is that and where in it is that proof?